# moving values to ax register but when printed the values are exchanged

Tags: assembly

I am trying to use the aam instruction and trying to print it. From the code below i've copied the ax reg to result, but when I try to print it, the output is reversed. In the code below i've tried to multiply 9 by 9, the output becomes 18. I don't know why. From what I've read ah becomes the tens place and al becomes the ones place. But when I try to move it to result, the values are exchange. Isn't ah supposed to be the first 8 bits in the ax reg? followed by al? I'm really confused here. Does using the mov instruction switch those positions? Can someone explain me why. I am new to assembly so bear with me. I am using Tasm btw, and is under Windows. Thanks.

```
.model small

.stack 100h

.data

num1 db 2 dup('0')

num2 db 2 dup('0')

result dw 2 dup('0')


.code
    main proc

    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    mov ah, 0
    mov al,9
    mov ah,9
    mul ah
    aam

    or ax, 3030h
    mov result, ax  


    mov dx, result
    mov ah, 02
    int 21h

    mov dx, result + 1
    mov ah, 02
    int 21h

    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h

main endp
end main
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Isn't ah supposed to be the first 8 bits in the ax reg? followed by al?

It depends what you mean by "first 8 bits". AL is the least significant 8 bits; if you number the bits from 0 to 15 then AL corresponds to bits 0 to 7 and AH corresponds to bits 8 through 15.

In your example you store the AX register to a memory location, `result`. Since the architecture is little-endian the contents of the AL register will then be found at `result` whereas the contents of AH will be at `result + 1`. You have mixed them up.

It is in fact the little-endian representation that determines where the AH value is stored relative to the AL value. You might want to read up on [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), but in brief, when you store a multiple-byte value, the least significant byte is stored at the *lowest* addressed memory location. This contrasts with big-endian architectures which do the opposite.

Comment: Wow. Thanks. But if I may ask, does this apply to everything when using the mov instruction? And also I've read about the big endianness and little endianness. And I think the problem that I'm having is the little one. Is there a way to determine if I'm having the little or big endian?

Comment: @random x86 is **always** little-endian. Also, endianess only is important when moving from registers to memory and vice versa.